# How to avoid scroll to the focussed element

Tags: javascript, html, focus

So, I have a input type=text that serves as a search.

The search, autoscrolls to the found item in long lists (so the input is outside the screen), but when I continue typing, after jumping to the first found result, it goes back up where the input is. I want to avoid such behaviour.

https://jsfiddle.net/ptjnr93q/

Please see the jsfiddle above.

```js
var cont = 0;
var fill = "test";
for (cont = 0; cont < 1000; cont++) {
    $("body").append(fill + "<br>");
 console.log("e");
}

$("input").bind('focusin focus', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type something in the input field, scroll down, and type again.<br>
The page scrolls up to the input again, I want to avoid it.<br>

<input type="text" class="search">
<br>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. How do you reproduce again that issue?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan type something in the input, and scroll down, without clicking outside, now, if you keep typing, the page will scroll back up, I want to avoid that behaviour

Comment: From a UI/UX perspective That's silly. You should make your input fixed and floating. So that I can see what I'm typing...

Comment: `window.onscroll = function() {
  $("input").trigger('blur');
}`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sure, but that does not answer my questoin

Comment: @Rayon again, that also makes no sense, you should be able to type. Adding your suggestion the input blurs and you're pretty much f*up

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan — I agree with you but that is what she asked :(

Comment: @Rayon no it's not what I asked, I want to keep typing, but not scroll up. Because my search function autoscrolls to the result, and if I go up, the page behaves like a retard.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I do have a floating headers for the table where I'm doing this approach, and it does have an input where I clone the text that I'm typing, but I can't just position it as absolute and solved. That's why I want to avoid the scroll.

Comment: @Dunnow — You could display only matched elements. That could remove the scrollbar...

Comment: @Rayon I already show matched elements, if the search is configured like that, but the search can behave in different manners depending on how it's coded to act. Still, this is not what I came here for, I don't want to filter out, I want to scroll to first matching element in this particular case

Comment: than simply remove all the `$("input").bind('focusin focus', function(e){` thing and you're done.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan eeer... no, removing the bind does not affect at all, same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I am proposing an another way to achieve your goal, which is keep the scrolled down position unchanged.

- Keep your resultSet in a separate DIV.
- Add scroll to resultSet div, so that even if focus move to input, your scolled position will remain unaffected

```js
    var cont = 0;
    var fill = "test";
    for (cont = 0; cont < 1000; cont++) {
        $("#resultSet").append(fill + cont + "<br>");
     //console.log("e");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="search">

    <br>
    
    <div id="resultSet" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;"></div>
```

Comment: @Dunnow, is this helpful?

Comment: It would, but that would mean changing the structure of a component that is used everywhere in the site, and that's provably a no go :S

Comment: Your page will be going to be used in android devices? Or in PCs?
There are ways available, if your target is an android device.

Comment: It wil supposedly only be used in computers, or, mainly only computers, you can access it through an Android device but it's not a responsive website as of yet, most of the application has screens dedicated to phones

Comment: @Dunnow, try this out, I think, it will be a small change.